# One Solr index for each day

Tags: solr, lucene

Requirements of the system that we are trying to build are for each date we need to create a SOLR index containing about 350-500 million documents , where each document is a single structured record having about 1000 fields .

Then query same based on index keys & date, for instance we will try to search records related to a particular user where date between Jan-1-2015 to Jan-31-2015. This query should load only indexes within this date range into memory and return rows corresponding to the search pattern.

Please suggest how this can be implemented using SOLR.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you can do this with SolrCloud:

- one collection per day
- number of shards/replication etc per collection set according to your needs (whats your query throughput...)
- additionally, if the number of collections start to be too many (see [this presentation about this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxRROble76A) you can further partition your data into several SolrCloud clusters (one per year/5 years or whatever)